# Form validation woes

Tags: javascript, html

New to JS guy here! I feel I have understanding of what my code is doing, but it still won't work.

The bug is (supposedly) with the validation for the phone number form, I have code that -as far as I know- should work (but does not).

Note that I have not got code to validate Address, post code and CC. The Idea is that I can apply your solutions to theses, seeing as they are similar to Phone number.

Also note I did try isNaN, but it was being "weird". Hope thats not too vague, but I'm sure some of you will "know" what I'm talking about.

Here we go (Sorry if my function is a bit long, let me know if its bad practice or whatever.)

Lets stay away from blunt answers if we can? I'd like to know whats wrong so I can fix it myself, walk me through it if you have the mind to be patient :)

JS and HTML:

```js
function detailCheck() {
  var phNoLength = document.getElementById('phNo').value.length;  //get value for phone number from form for checking
  var cardNoLength = document.getElementById('cardNo').value.length; //get value for card number length for checking 
  var postCodeLength = document.getElementById("postCode").value.length //get value for post code length
  var a = /^[A-Za-z]+$/; 
  var b = /^[-+]?[0-9]+$/; 
 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   details = document.getElementById("myForm")[i].value;
   if (details === "") {
     var i = ("Please enter ALL your details."); 
     document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;
    return;
    } else {
    
     if(phNoLength != 7) {

      var i = "Please use a phone number with a length of 7"; 
      document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML = i;    
     } else {
      if(b.test(document.getElementById("phNo").value)) {   
       
       if(postCodeLength === 4){   
         
        var f_nameLength = document.getElementById('fName').value.length; 
        var l_nameLength = document.getElementById('lName').value.length; 

        if(f_nameLength < 3) {   
         var i = "First name not long enough"
         document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;

        } else {

          if(a.test(document.getElementById("fName").value)) {    
         if(l_nameLength < 3) {
               var i = "Last name not long enough"
               document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;

                } else {

                  if(a.test(document.getElementById("lName").value)) {
                   
                    if(cardNoLength === 4) {
                      
                     if(isNaN(cardNoLength)) {
                           var i = "Your card number must be numbers only";
                          document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;

                        } else {
                          //---- End result ----//
                             toggleContent();
                          //--------------------//
                        }
                      } else {
                        var i = "Your card number must have four numbers";
                       document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML = i;
                      }
                  } else {    
                    var i = "Please only use letters in your last name";
                    document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;
                  }
                }
            } else {
            var i = "Please only use letters in your first name";
             document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;
            }

        }  
       } else {
     var i = "Please use a post code with a length of four";
     document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML = i;
       }
   } else {
     var i = "only use numbers in your Phone number";
     document.getElementById("formTital").innerHTML=i;
   }
}
}
}
}
```

```html
 <form id="myForm" action="form_action.asp">
    First name: <br> <input class="formInput" type="text" id="fName" name="fName"><br>
    Last name: <br> <input class="formInput" type="text" id="lName" name="lName"><br>
    Phone Number: <br> <input class="formInput" type="number" id="phNo" name="phNo" maxlength="7"><br>
    Credit Card Number: <br> <input class="formInput" type="password" id="cardNo" name="cardNo" maxlength="4"><br>
    Address: <br> <input class="formInput" type="text" id="address" name="address"><br>
    Post code: <br> <input class="formInput" type="number" id="postCode" name="postCode" maxlength="4"><br>
   </form>
```

Comment: That's a *lot* of nested `if`s...

Comment: This a bad thing? How would you set conditions like theses?

Comment: Not necessarily a bad thing, but I personally think they get very confusing, especially depending on the indentation.

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code in the browser and try to debug your code?

Comment: Nothing unexpected as far as I can see. Nothing outstandingly obvious then?

Comment: For those that worry about nesting, you can eliminate the top one since when true, your function turns. Hence, you can just make the first if without else and continue with the rest following this first if (which, if true, returns and hence what follows it would not execute). As per your question, I don't quite understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

It is not obvious when you want the validation to occur (you included a function but it is not clear whether you want it to be an event handler or not).

Your regex seems to be fine. I am including a stripped-down JSFiddle with a single `input` to which I attached an event handler for `keyup` and showed the result of `.test()` for your regex.

[See it here](https://jsfiddle.net/y5qbs66b/3/).

In regards to your code, it is fairly messy. In terms of form validation. I assume you meant to display a single status message for the user, so you would want to you want to first figure out the priority of your validation. One cleaner option would be to use a function with ordered `return`s, for example take this pseudo-code:

```
function getErrorMessage(){
  // if name is invalid
  //            return 'Your name is invalid.';
  // if phone is invalid
  //            return 'Your phone is invalid.';
  // ...
  // return '';
}
```

Nesting so many conditional statements can lead to very messy, very non-maintainable spaghetti code. If you are new to Javascript, it is best to learn the best practices early on, as it will save you a lot of headache and facepalms in the future.

If I did not understand your question correctly, please let me know.

Comment: I'm thinking of re programming this function -just to make it not messy. But there are just so many conditions to check for! Any advice on how to deal with this? Separate functions mayhaps?

Comment: It does not have to be complicated, if you want to recreate this type of design, just decide on what you feel is the appropriate order of validation, go for that.
I feel as though a natural UX would be to have the invalid message for the last input that was blurred and was invalid. Read up on form validation and UI/UX regarding that.